# How to keep rows in which var1 value is more than 17?

Tags: dataframe, sas

I have data `mydata`

```
id  |  var1  |  var2  | var3
1       |1       |1         |1
2       |33       |1         |1
3      |1        |1         |1
4       |22      |1         |1
5       |1        |1         |1
6      |1       |1         |1
```

How to keep rows in which `var1` value is more than `17`?

So I should receive:

```
id  |  var1  |  var2  | var3
2       |33       |1         |1
4       |22      |1         |1
```

Comment: You should be showing an attempt with your questions please. If you're just learning SAS, SAS has two free e-courses that cover these topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data gt17;
  set mydata;
  where var1 > 17;
run;
```

Comment: Can you share the log?

Comment: After I drop and recreate it I use your code. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to drop age_group_var and recreate it again after. That is not how SAS works. The drop statement will remove the variable regardless of where it is placed in the code. So there are no records with age_group_var defined to begin with. Do this:

`data sas_stata;
  set sas_stata (rename = (age_group_var = age_group_var_tmp));

  <Everything Else>

  age_group_var = input(age_group_var_tmp, 8.);
  drop age_group_var_tmp;

run;`